# No module named 'encodings' , apache2 + wsgi /+virtualenv

Tags: apache, virtualenv, wsgi

I have developped a website with django, it perfectly works locally but now I want to deploy it 
I have the following error in my error.log ( apache2 logs )

Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError : No module named 'encodings'

As many topics suggest it I have removed my venv and created it again, but I still get the same error.

Do you have any idea how to deal with that ?

ps: static files are working normally

Comment: I now have this error : Import Error cannot import name 'remove_dead_weakred'

Comment: Now it seems to work a bit better, but I have Import Error no module named math , It looks like it cannot import module that are not included in the env